# Python Error: "ValueError: too many values to unpack"

Tags: python

I'm trying to save a .txt file to a dictionary and then print it...

```
a_dictionary = {}

a_file = open("books.txt") #file .txt I try to open to save in the dictionary

for line in a_file:
  
 key, value = line.split()
 a_dictionary[key] = value

print(line)
```

*It shows me the following error:*

**ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)**

Comment: Una la línea del archivo tiene más de dos palabras.

Comment: Estás en SO en español, por favor, traduce la pregunta o trasládala a SO en inglés.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes más de dos palabras en una misma línea. Tendrías que revisar y corregir el texto.

La otra alternativa es simplemente forzar la división a un máximo de dos partes, usando el parámetro `maxsplit`, dando el **número** de divisiones que quieres hacer. En tu caso, quieres hacer una división para obtener dos partes:

```
linea = "llave valor y otro valor"
key, value = linea.split(maxsplit=1)
print(f"llave: {key}")
print(f"valor: {value}")
```

produce:

```
llave: llave
valor: valor y otro valor

Process finished with exit code 0
```

De esta manera no importa cuantas palabras estén asociadas a la llave.